# Send and receive 868Mhz signals with my Pi

Tags: hardware, wireless, radio, signal

My home lighting is achieved using wireless Delta Dore switches working in 868 Mhz. 
Here are my switches reference : https://www.deltadore.fr/data/product_files/6351091/documents/notices/Util/fr/web_TYXIA%202610_20_30_40_50_emet_micromodules_2702540_rev4-rev04.pdf

I'd like to sniff my switches signals (On/OFF Commands) in order to be able to command my lightings via a web interface for example.

Do you think it's possible?
If yes, can someone advise me a transceiver compatible to a pi able to do this?

I found a lot of articles about 433Mhz but noting about 868Mhz.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Any software which works for 434MHz should also work for 868MHz.

E.g. my http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2__433D may work.